# Page took too long to load

Tags: magento-1.9, pagespeed

I am having a problem with the speed of the website. I dont know for sure where the problem is, even gtmetrix gets an error while analyzing it. Does anyone know how I can solve this? This is the link to my site: https://goo.gl/yCbPPM

Thanks!

Comment: did you solve this issue?

Comment: Yes this is solved. Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be an external script that is timing out just before body end. This seems to be a visitor tracking tool but the script just times out and **agent.extrawatch.com** just seems completely unavailable. Try removing below your site should speed up.

```
<script src="https://agent.extrawatch.com/extrawatch/agent/js/?projectId=86105afd34d547a982faac501c839fe996f40de5" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Maybe worth contacting **extrawatch.com** to see why the scripts are no longer available and where to get the new links if you need to keep the tracking functionality from here.